# Partition SQL result by ID per (batch) size

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a recordset output from SQL which I want to use in our production where I want to identify each production order (prodid) with a batch number, based on a specific batch size.

Sample data (here each production order has one item but it can be X items per production order):

```
SET nocount ON
DECLARE @FirstTable TABLE (ProdId NVARCHAR(10), ItemID NVARCHAR(10))
DECLARE @ii INT


SET @ii = 1
WHILE @ii < 50
  BEGIN
    INSERT  INTO @FirstTable
    VALUES  ('P' + convert(varchar(10),@ii), 'I'+ convert(varchar(10),@ii * 10))
    SET @ii = @ii + 1
  END

SELECT  * FROM    @FirstTable
```

If for instance the batch size is 3 I want to have batches with 3 production orders in each batch,  my required result is:

[image]

If for instance the batch size is 4 I want to have batches with 4 production orders in each batch,  my required result is:

[image]

Of course the last batch will be less than the batch size most of the times.
Can anyone tell me how to do this in SQL?

Comment: Can you provide input data, because I am not getting the point from where ItemId is coming up and I couldn't figure out the desired logic as well.

Comment: Thnx sabhari, edited..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `dense_rank()` to generate a sequence no by `ProdId`. After that, use following expression `(SeqNo - 1) / @batch_size + 1` to obtain your `BatchId`

```
select  *, 
        BatchId = (SeqNo - 1) / @batch_size + 1
from
(
    select  *, 
            SeqNo = dense_rank() over (order by ProdId)
    from    yourtable
) d
```

Comment: Perfect! Thnx a million Squirrel, you're a lifesaver :)